# How to accept invitation links using Dropbox API V2

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

Using the Dropbox V2 API, is it possible to interact with sharing invitation URLs or file request URLs? I'd like for unauthenticated users to be able to view public folders or upload to file requests, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do this with the current API. Am I missing something or is this just not supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't much support for interacting with shared folder invitation and file request links like this via the Dropbox API, but we'll consider it a feature request.

Specifically:

- Links for shared folder invitations: This is more meant for manual human use. If your app is connected to the recipient's account though, you can list the shared folders they've been invited to via [/2/sharing/list_mountable_folders](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_mountable_folders)[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_mountable_folders-continue), and add them to their account via [/2/sharing/mount_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-mount_folder).
- Shared links: As opposed to actual shared folders, the API does offer some ability to programmatically interact with shared links (whether for files or folders), in case that's helpful. You can get information about a shared link using [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_metadata), list the contents of a shared link for a folder via [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue), and download a file from a shared link via [/2/sharing/get_shared_link_file](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-get_shared_link_file). (Or, see [this help article](https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download) for information on downloading from shared links directly.)
- File request links: This is also meant for manual human use. The Dropbox API doesn't offer a way to programmatically upload to these.